# Throwing out of range exception for DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, exception

I have a quick question. I am not sure what is the best way of going about this.
Should I throw an out of range exception for DateTime? Because I want to make my code as idiot proof as possible.

At the bottom is my code. Is this a good way of throwing the exception? When i don't throw an out of range exception a argumentexception happens. Should i throw an argument exception instead? Are these correct parameters to put in my exception. What's the best way of going about this? Is this a good way to throw exceptions in general?

Thanks

```
private DateTime date;
public SimpleDate(int day, int month, int year)
{
    if (day > 31 || day < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("day");
    }
    if (month > 12 || month < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("month");
    }
    if (year > 2100 || year < 1900)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year");
    }
    date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
}
```

Comment: try to use more expressive message if u can

Comment: I don't understand the point of this code, the DateTime constructor has an overload for year/month/day and throws an error if they're invalid. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: When I just let the exception happen I get an argument exception. Not an out of range exception. So that might be misleading? I don't know. Doesn't throwing exceptions also help with debugging? Instead of just letting the exception happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good approach from a conceptual standpoint; your object is in the best position to know what's valid input, not your object's caller. However, obviously your logic is not complete; there are some significant "corner cases" like February 31st. It's also a duplication of work.

The [DateTime constructor accepting Year, Month and Day](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) will validate that the combination of these numbers yields a valid date, and will throw its own ArgumentOutOfRange exception if it isn't. That validation is much more complete; not only will it validate the correct number of days in each month, it will do leap year calculations as well to determine whether February 29th is valid for the specified year. Best of all, *it already exists*; As Equalsk said in his comment, why reinvent the wheel?

So, the overwhelming majority of your validation should come from simply trying to construct a new Date from the entered numbers, and letting the DateTime constructor throw out as needed. You can add your own more restrictive validation on top of that as you please; for instance, restricting the entered year to between 1900 and 2100 (System.DateTime is capable of handling any four-digit year in the "common era", 0001 to 9999).

Comment: But then why ever throw exceptions. By following your logic you just let exceptions happen, because datetime alreadys throws one.  Also, i get an argument exception when i don't check my parameters for datetime. Instead of an argumentOutOfRange exception. Can you clarify on this?

Comment: The MSDN docs state an ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown, but the docs have been known to be wrong. If you must have an ArgumentOutOfRange exception, you may catch and examine the ArgumwentException to determine which argument the constructor rejected, and throw an AOOR exception for the same parameter of your constructor.

Comment: Should I test the build in exception from MSDN in my test case ?

Comment: Your test case should expect the exception that you want to have thrown out of your constructor given invalid date parameters. Whether that lines up with what DateTime actually throws is something you'll have to check; if you have a unit test suite for this object (if so, good coder, have a Red Bull), then just run it and see what happens. If you get the wrong exception type, you can catch and rethrow.

Comment: @MathijsF :-) just remember that your definition of valid from your OP is more restrictive than DateTime's with respect to the year, so in addition to constructing the DateTime, you can and should validate that the year falls in your narrower range (1900-2100).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with throwing an exception, it is generally a good idea to validate your data that is being inputted.

One thing I did notice, shouldn't

`if (month > 12 || month < 0)` be 
`if (month > 12 || month <= 0)`. 0 wouldn't be a valid month. :)

Comment: Depends on whether the OP wants zero-based month ordinals like JavaScript. If so, then it would be `if (month > 11 || month < 0)`. zero-based works well for translation to an array of month names, less useful for constructing a custom date numeral string.